Optimizing Pandas GroupBy and Aggregation on Large Datasets with Multiple Custom Functions
I'm working with a large Pandas dataframe (about 30.5 million rows) where I need to group by multiple columns and apply different custom aggregation functions. However, the performance is currently a bottleneck.
Here's a simplified version of my current approach:
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'] * 10**6,
    'subcategory': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'] * 10**6,
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4] * 10**6,
    'quantity': [10, 20, 30, 40] * 10**6
})
 
agg_functions = {
    'value': ['sum', 'mean'],
    'quantity': [lambda x: x.sum(), lambda x: (x > 20).mean()]
}

result = df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory']).agg(agg_functions)

Problems:
1. The dataframe is too large, and the above code runs out of memory when working with real data.
2. Some custom aggregation functions (like the lambda functions for quantity) are slow and prevent the efficient use of vectorized operations.
3. I want to apply these aggregations in a more memory-efficient way without resorting to chunking the data.
Questions:
1. How can I optimize the groupby and agg operations to handle large datasets more efficiently, especially when applying custom functions?
2. Are there any advanced techniques, such as using numba, cython, or parallel processing, to speed up custom aggregations within a Pandas groupby?
3. Would converting the dataframe to a different structure, such as using Polars, Dask, or PySpark, provide significant performance improvements in this case, or is there a way to keep it in Pandas and still optimize the performance?
I'm looking for both performance tips for memory management and speed optimizations while maintaining the flexibility of custom aggregations. Any guidance on best practices or advanced techniques would be appreciated!
What I’ve Tried:
1. Basic GroupBy with Pandas: I started by using Pandas' groupby() function with custom aggregation functions (e.g., lambda functions), but it was too slow for my dataset, which has millions of rows. The lambda functions, especially for conditional aggregation, significantly slowed down the performance.
2. Optimizing Memory Usage: I attempted to reduce memory consumption by converting columns to more efficient data types (category for categorical data, int32 for integers), but while it helped with memory, the execution time for the groupby and aggregation was still very slow.
3. Chunking Data: I tried to process the data in chunks using pd.read_csv() with chunksize, but managing the chunks and performing the groupby operations across chunks became difficult, and merging results added more overhead.
4. Multithreading with joblib: I used joblib to parallelize the application of custom aggregation functions, but the performance gain was minimal, likely due to the nature of the custom lambda functions and the overhead of managing multiple threads.
5. Dask DataFrame: I experimented with Dask to distribute the workload across multiple cores, but managing custom functions and ensuring all operations were distributed efficiently added complexity without significantly improving performance.

import pandas as pd  # pip install  pandas
import numpy as np # pip install numpy
from numba import njit  # pip install numba


class DataFrameOptimizer:
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.df = dataframe
        self._optimize_memory_usage()

    def _optimize_memory_usage(self):
        """
        Data type conversion to reduce memory consumption.
        """
        for col in self.df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']).columns:
            self.df[col] = pd.to_numeric(self.df[col], downcast='unsigned')
        for col in self.df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
            num_unique_values = len(self.df[col].unique())
            num_total_values = len(self.df[col])
            if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
                self.df[col] = self.df[col].astype('category')

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def _conditional_mean_numba(values):
        """
        Speeding up conditional average calculation using Numba.
        """
        count = 0
        total = 0
        for val in values:
            if val > 20:
                total += 1
            count += 1
        return total / count if count > 0 else 0

    def optimized_groupby_agg(self):
        """
        Optimized groupby method using vectorization and Numba.
        """
        # Defining standard aggregations for the 'value' column
        agg_value = self.df['value'].agg(['sum', 'mean'])

        # Using a custom function with Numba for 'quantity'
        quantity_values = self.df['quantity'].values
        conditional_mean = DataFrameOptimizer._conditional_mean_numba(
            quantity_values)
        quantity_sum = np.sum(quantity_values)

        result = {
            'value_sum': agg_value['sum'],
            'value_mean': agg_value['mean'],
            'quantity_sum': quantity_sum,
            'quantity_conditional_mean': conditional_mean
        }
        return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'] * 10**6,
        'subcategory': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'] * 10**6,
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4] * 10**6,
        'quantity': [10, 20, 30, 40] * 10**6
    })

    optimizer = DataFrameOptimizer(df)
    print(optimizer.optimized_groupby_agg())


